# How to access server folders from one account using credentials from another account

Tags: windows-7, permissions, shared-folders, credentials

We are running Windows Small Business Server 2011 (which is really Server 2008 R2) on a Windows domain network with Windows 7 clients in an office setting.  Each user's local My Documents folder on their domain PCs has been redirected to point to a folder on the server.

This means that we have a folder on the server that contains everyone's My Document folders.  This folder can be mapped by people who know the address.

There is a Windows 7 computer in a conference room.  We want to be able to login to that computer (local or roaming profile) with a specific profile (example username: conferenceroom).  We then want to map the folder containing all the My Documents folders so that the user can 1) browse the list of users' My Documents folders to find the correct one and 2) ONLY be able to open/access the folder and its contents if they put in that specific user's credentials (ex: they can only access USER01's My Documents folder if they know USER01's Windows password).

Our final goal is that a user comes into the conference room, logs into the PC with the conferenceroom user account, navigates to the mapped drive, browses for a specific user's My Documents folder (usually their own) and then is prompted to input their username and password before they are can get access to the folder and its contents.  This would allow users to EASILY access their own documents when giving a presentation while not having to login as themselves and then tweak/install the computer's applications (we don't use roaming profiles).

We would also want the machine to NOT cache the credentials and to force users to login to the folder every time.  This way, if a user simply closes their folder, it "logs off" the shared folder.

UPDATE:

We put the computer on its own workgroup (but still connected to the network via Ethernet cable) and then mapped the drive with the folders in question.  We then were prompted to put in the domain admin password to finalize mapping the drive.  After that, we were prompted to input user credentials when we needed to access each folder.  However, we could not get Windows 7 to forget the credentials, so it would save it.  We didn't check if restarting or simply logging off would cause Windows to forget the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without scripting is to make a shortcut for each user to the command

`runas.exe /user:<domainname>\<username> "windows.exe <uncpathname>"`

i.e.

Mary's Files.lnk -> `runas.exe /user:ourdomain\mary "windows.exe \\fileserver\mary$"`
Steve's Files.lnk -> `runas.exe /user:ourdomain\steve "windows.exe \\fileserver\steve$"`
Bob's Files.lnk -> `runas.exe /user:ourdomain\bob "windows.exe \\fileserver\bob$"`

For this to work properly both the conference room computer and the fileserver must be joined to a domain within the same tree, although it may work if they are in the same forrest.